# trouble compiling chrome native client tutorial

Tags: google-nativeclient

I tried following the tutorial here for NaCl or PNaCl or native client or pinnacle whatever the name of the day is and got this:

F:/nacl_sdk/pepper_31/toolchain/win_x86_newlib/bin/i686-nacl-g++ -o hello_tutori
al_x86_32.nexe hello_tutorial_32.o -m32 -O0 -g -IF:/nacl_sdk/pepper_31/include -
lppapi_cpp -lppapi
/x86_64-nacl-ld: cannot find -lppapi_cpp
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:64: recipe for target 'hello_tutorial_x86_32.nexe' failed
make: *** [hello_tutorial_x86_32.nexe] Error 1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running the old "hello_tutorial" example with the new pepper_31 SDK. Please use this new documentation instead:

https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/devguide/tutorial/tutorial-part1

This source for this tutorial can be found in the pepper_31 SDK in the directory `pepper_31\getting_started\part1`.

Comment: Following that, now when I 'make serve' or 'make' anything I get 'The procedure entry point __assert_func could not be located in the dynamic link library cygwin1.dll.'

Comment: A quick google search shows that you are likely running an older version of cygwin. See, for example, this FAQ: http://puttycyg.googlecode.com/svn-history/r32/wiki/FAQ.wiki. Try updating to a newer version cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

The new tutorial cited by binji is set up to build/run a pexe. To use nexe's as in the older example, update the tutorial's Makefile:

Add `LDFLAGS` for each target:

```
LDFLAGS_NEWLIB_ARM    := -L$(NACL_SDK_ROOT)/lib/newlib_arm/Release -lppapi_cpp -lppapi
LDFLAGS_NEWLIB_X86_32 := -L$(NACL_SDK_ROOT)/lib/newlib_x86_32/Release -lppapi_cpp -lppapi
LDFLAGS_NEWLIB_X86_64 := -L$(NACL_SDK_ROOT)/lib/newlib_x86_64/Release -lppapi_cpp -lppapi
```

and change the `$(LDFLAGS)` specified for linking the respective targets.